# Issues checking if Map contains key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a function that returns the prime factors of integers as a Map in JavaScript.
My code is as follows:

```js
function getPrimeFactorsBelow(n) {
  var factors = new Map();

  for (let i = 2; i < n / 2 + 1; i++) {
    if (!factors.has(i)) {
      for (let j = i * 2; j < n; j += i) {
        if (!factors.has(j)) {
          factors[j] = [i];
        } else {
          factors[j].push(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return factors;
}

console.log(getPrimeFactorsBelow(10));
```

However, the `else` part never executes, as though `.has()` doesn't detect that the map contains the keys.
What am I missing?

Comment: You never add a key to the map *properly*. That's done with [`.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set). Attaching a random property to the map does not treat the map *as a map*. Conversely, to read the value of that property, you need [`.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get). So, *either* use a plain object *or* use a map. Don't just mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an element to a  Map use the `set` method.
To get an element use the `get` method.
Is this what you want to achieve ?

```js
function getPrimeFactorsBelow(n) {
    var factors = new Map();

    for (let i = 2; i < n / 2 + 1; i++) {
        if (!factors.has(i)) {
            for (let j = i * 2; j < n; j += i) {
                if (!factors.has(j)) {
                   factors.set(j, []);
                }
               factors.get(j).push(i);
            }
       }
   }

  return factors;
```